# Zombie.js "assert is not defined" for multiple visits?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, zombie.js, chai

I'm setting up integration testing with Zombie.js and Mocha, and running into the puzzling problem that only the first `browser.visit()` call seems to succeed. My specs look like this:

```
browser = new Browser site: "http://localhost:101010"

describe '/docs', ->
  ['app', 'server', 'timetable', 'util'].forEach (file) ->
    describe "/#{file}.html", -> it "documents #{file}.coffee", (done) ->
      browser.visit "/docs/#{file}.html", ->
        browser.text('title').should.equal "#{file}.coffee"
        do done
```

The *first* of those tests, which loads `/docs/app.html`, passes without incident. However, all subsequent tests fail, producing a stacktrace like the following:

```
 ReferenceError: assert is not defined
  at Object.HTML5Parser.phases.inBody.startTagBody (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/parser.js:1828:4)
  at Object.HTML5Parser.phases.base.processStartTag (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/parser.js:65:40)
  at EventEmitter.Parser.do_token (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/parser.js:2436:21)
  at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/parser.js:2457:30)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at EventEmitter.emitToken (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:99:9)
  at emit_current_token (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:873:3)
  at tag_name_state (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:400:4)
  at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:941:10)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at EventEmitter.HTML5Tokenizer.pump (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:932:11)
  at EventEmitter.HTML5Tokenizer.tokenize (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:89:23)
  at EventEmitter.Parser.parse (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/parser.js:2391:17)
  at HtmlToDom.appendHtmlToElement (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/htmltodom.js:91:50)
  at Object.innerHTML (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:481:17)
  at Object.core.HTMLDocument.write (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:406:22)
  at Object.exports.jsdom (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:70:9)
  at History._createDocument (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.js:174:22)
  at /home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.js:126:30
  at /home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/resources.js:147:16
  at Request._callback (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/resources.js:335:16)
  at Request.self.callback (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/request/main.js:120:22)
  at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at Request.<anonymous> (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/request/main.js:633:16)
  at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/$USER/projects/timetable/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/request/main.js:595:14)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at _stream_readable.js:872:14
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Is Zombie's `browser.visit()` not intended to be called more than once, or is there some other issue here?

Editing to note versions:

- Node.js v0.10.1
- Mocha v1.8.1
- Chai v1.5.0
- Zombie.js v1.4.1

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is a compatibility issue arising in Node versions >=0.10, as mentioned here: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/487

The workaround mentioned at https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/487#issuecomment-15548684 solves my particular problem. I added the following code to my `testi/common.coffee` file immediately before importing Zombie:

```
do patchEventEmitterToHideMaxListenerWarning = ->
  return if global.eventEmitterPatched
  global.eventEmitterPatched = true
  events = require 'events'
  Old = events.EventEmitter
  events.EventEmitter = ->
    this.setMaxListeners(0)
  events.EventEmitter.prototype = Old.prototype
```

Having done so, all my tests pass without complaint. I expect that this issue will be patched up in future Zombie revisions, but for now the above hack renders it workable.